# MySQL workbench error - "Could not encrypt password cache"

Tags: mysql-workbench

when creating a new connection and when inserting the password for the username in mysql workbench i'm getting the error of "Could not encrypt password cache"

can anyone suggest a solution ?

[image]

Comment: Operating System? Did you try and use someone elses Password Storage Vault? Or one you created somewhere else?

Comment: windows 11. I reset my computer due to a issue and reinstalled mysql-workbench again by providing new credentials. and i have created a new connection(not root username) and when providing password for that username this error came

Answer (score 0):

That's part of the security concept in Windows. Once you encrypted data with a  specific user, only this user can also decrypt it. It's not possible to use a different user, even if that was created with the same name + password.

You have to remove the password vault from the MySQL Workbench data dir and enter (and store) the MySQL password(s) again.